# Read XML in Powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Note: When use `Get-Host` getting Version: 2.0 in powershell.
In Windows 2008 server, executed below code to create domainlist.xml file at System32 folder.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\rendom.exe" -ArgumentList "/list"
```

Using below query to read the xml but it is error out.

```
$path = "C:\Users\074129\Desktop\Domainlist.xml"
$xml = [xml](Get-Content -Path $path)
$xml.Forest.Domain.NetBiosName[2]
```

Error Message: `Cannot index into a null array`

No value is returning even for '$xml.Forest' command.

Please help to read and replace the node value in domainlist.xml file.

Let me know if any additional details required from my end.

Comment: You don't set the `$path` variable, as it is marked as a comment: `#$path`. Is this a typo? If not, please edit the question and add the XML content tool

Comment: It is a typo error while asking the question. Update accordingly.

Comment: I checked on my test DC and this is running fine `$xml.Forest.Domain.NetBiosName`

Comment: @Abhijithpk, Have you used PowerShell Version 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your situation you cannot get NetBiosName node from Domainlist.xml. Actually, there is a scenario when all NetBiosName nodes are empty that's why you should check them first (the reasons of this behavior are different).

```
$xml = 'C:\Users\074129\Desktop\Domainlist.xml'
if (($col = Select-Xml -Path $xml -XPath //NetBiosName) -is [Array]) {
  $col[2].Node
  # or if you need find all non-empty nodes
  # $col | Where-Object {$_.Node.'#text' -ne $null}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem of old powershell versions.
It should work if you load the xml manually instead if I remember correctly:

```
$path = "C:\Users\074129\Desktop\Domainlist.xml"
$xml = New-Object -TypeName "System.Xml.XmlDocument"
$xml.Load($path)
$xml.Forest.Domain.NetBiosName[2]
```